# High and low rebus

Tags: word, rebus, computer-puzzle, cryptic-clues, tribond

What may the following represent?

> $\large\underline{US}$
>
> $\large01100111$
>
> $\large00\Large\color{green}\bullet$

The 3 rebuses give 3 proper nouns. They are in alphabetical and chronological order starting in the:

- 1990s
- 2000 - 2009
- 2010s

(the first being more general than the next two). They are a tribond, so have something in common.

---

An alternative & standalone way to find this connection, which is a 6 letter word, is the cryptic clue:

> Seal companion is ferret. (6)

Comment: 01100111 = g in ascii

Comment: Something of sort - "Under weight goes green"?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the rebuses are spelling out:

> 1. America Online? (The united states, on top of a line)
>  2. Bing (Binary G) [EDIT: looks like Riley got this one before me]
>  
>  3. Duck Duck Go (Zero being a 'duck', green being 'go')

The title suggests:

> Searching high and low

The cryptic suggests

> Searching for hidden things

Because

> To seal something is to close or hide away, and the companion is to ferret out the truth.

So, my answer is:

> search

Comment: This is an excellent interpretation of the cryptic clue.

Comment: I think this could be right! Although it looks like I got the second part of the rebus first.

Comment: Excellent, that definitely sounds right

Comment: Super, all correct except ironically for the cryptic clue, which has the same answer as the rebus connection. I will accept soon - someone may fit the CC to the answer.

Comment: @Tom I am not sure about the CC, but it's probably SEA+RCH although I confess I can't see how RCH=companion.

Comment: @Sid Not quite. The split is a (cookery) synonym of seal + a cryptic abbreviation for companion. I hope OK!

Comment: @Tom So... Sear+ CH(where CH= Companions of Honour?)

Comment: That sounds right.

Comment: Yes, my clue isn't the best surface but that's what I was going for (do see CH used for this).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it could be

> Goes green over us(with prejudice/envy)

As,

> 01100111 if ASCII 'g' as identified by Amruth and 00 are taken as **OES** (plural of O literally, but here of 0s) and those are below the word *Us*.

Comment: I feel like, given the positions in the rebus, this would be *under* instead of *over*.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about the others, but the second one might represent...

> Bing

because

> It's a **Bin**ary **g**. Also, Bing is a proper noun, and it started in 2009.

Answer (score 3):

This might seem an answer out of left field, but, I'm guessing it refers to a:

> **WEASEL**

Title: High and Low Rebus

> The suffix "sel" sounds like "sell", which is a trading activity that occurs either high or low (e.g. sell when high).

US

> Synonym for "we", which is the prefix of the answer.

Cryptic clue: Seal companion is ferret. (6)

> [Seals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinniped) are closely related to the [Musteloidea superfamily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musteloidea) (to which ferrets belong), and [weasels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel) are a genus under that.

TODO: I'm yet to determine how this relates to the $01100111$ and $00\color{green}\bullet$. I'm currently thinking the ASCII 'g' is used to denote an abbreviation for

> Genus, as that ties in with the cryptic clue's answer.

Comment: I don't understand how that cryptic clue works...

Comment: @Sid - I've edited the answer, does that help?

Comment: I thought it would be less stretchy than that.

Comment: Wow! That seems right :)

Comment: @AbcDexter - Thank you. However, I am inclined towards what Sid said, some of my explanations feel like they were stretched to fit!

Comment: I'm looking for a different answer, but it's interesting to learn of a relation between seals and ferrets!

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer:

00 Green could represent

> zero on a roulette wheel. Or just the word roulette

Really going out on a limb, 01100111

> is a binary g. So you could be looking for a binary star of spectral type g, of which apparently Alpha Centauri A is one. But that's really a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

This is extremely far afield, and it doesn't really match the cryptic clue, but I think there's a low probability it is

> subway

Where I interpret the rebus as:

> "US" Meaning the people, and the line that goes under them. Then collectively, "01100111" as the ASCII code point for "g", and the dot as the color green, which I take to mean together the Manhattan G subway, which has a lime green color as its color.

I'm also unsure, because

> I never used the "00" before the green dot. Perhaps you were referring to the first stop, which would be "queens," another 6 letter word. Further, "subway" doesn't match the cryptic clue in any directly meaningful way.

Comment: The first sentence of your rebus interpretation is very much along the right lines, though you could make even more specific. Each of the 3 rebuses give a separate proper noun, and what these 3 have in common is the 6 letter word, for which the CC provides an alternative standalone definition.

Comment: @Tom That's a whopping hint more than a guess at the right direction, you should probably add that to the OP if you are going to say that here as well

Comment: that's fair and I've added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

A guess:  $U_s$

> ...looks like a source (or supply, or input) voltage

and the underscore

> may denote a [complex representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_impedance#Complex_voltage_and_current) in AC circuit analysis

...but I'm stuck here. :(

Comment: It is not Us but U8 (Upper U with a subscript - 8 - that is **number** 8)

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay,  s not 8 is the character following U in the question.

Comment: @Tom I think Mea means not s but 8 for *source voltage* mentioned in the answer

Comment: Thanks @Alex for noticing this! Apologies Mea Culpa if I misinterpreted (I think the font makes it look like 8). The rebus may be better written as upper-case S (it would be clearer/easier) and if stopping people answering I might update sometime and possibly put a dot after the S.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is to do something with:

> Use; as multiple Us can be pronounced

So, could be:

> Use over Goes Green